# How to fetch data from SolarWinds Access Right Manager product?

Tags: database, data-retrieval, solarwinds-orion, solarwindslem

Currently, I am working on the SolarWinds ARM Product. I am supposed to fetch the data from the ARM and perform some functions on that data.

In order to get that data, I tried to find the API Documentation, SDK of the SolarWinds ARM Product, but couldn't find it. Also I tried to fetch the data from the database itself through SQL queries, but with that too was unable to get the required data response.